# Transloco translateService.translate does not work in app.component.ts

Tags: angular, typescript, translation, transloco

If I enter the below in my app.component.ts constructor, it does not work.

```
alert(this.translateService.translate('navigation.dashboard'));
```

However if I enter this same code in a submodule, it works fine.

This is my .json file:

```
    "navigation": {
    "dashboard": "Dashboard"
   }
```

In my app.module.ts, the TranslocoRootModule is imported too.

```
import { TranslocoRootModule } from './transloco/transloco-root.module';

imports: [
 ...  
 HttpClientModule,
 TranslocoRootModule
],
```

Did I miss out anything?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well. What I realized was that the transloco file (i.e. the json file) had not yet loaded when I was trying to get the translation. It seems like the order in which the HTTP requests are being made does not allows all translations json file to load before the component does.

This means, that if you are on a different page, and then navigate to this page through angular, it will/would work (because the translations file has been loaded). This only seemed to be the problem for a refresh on a current page.

In order to get around this, here's what I did:

```
...
constructor(private translocoService: TranslocoService,
  private translocoHttpLoader: TranslocoHttpLoader ...) {
...
}

ngOnInit(): void {
...
this.translocoHttpLoader.getTranslation(this.translocoService.getActiveLang())).subscribe(translation => {
  alert(translation.navigation.dashboard);
})
...
}
```

Hope this example helps.

Comment: I have the same problem but this solution does not work for me

Comment: What's the error that you are getting?

Comment: It didn't see the translation. After some hours I think it's because of the way ng-zorro breadcrumbs were taking the translate funkction. I changed the code to just plainly pass the value and transformed it with transloco pipe which solved my issue.

Comment: Oh that's great. I'm glad you were able to find the solution :)